# Add audio and video codec to iTunes

Tags: itunes

I have a dream... One day my iTunes could read also MKV and all other codecs that are not natively supporter by it...

Is there a solution for make this reality? I have `ffmpeg` tool installed in my mac, and also lots of codecs.

Can I "install" one of this codec in my iTunes and make it read also MKV?

Comment: Is "no" a sufficient answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question used to be "install [Perian](http://www.perian.org/)", and although that still works and provides many great codecs for Quicktime (and therefore iTunes), it's discontinued.

Give it a go, it's always worked really well for me.

Comment: Maybe more custom solution? like some injection in iTunes code? :D